# ¿Cómo puedo sumar dos elementos de cada fila en una iteración?

Tags: python

Hola amigos de Stack Over Flow deseo realizar una suma de cada dos elementos por cada fila, haciendo una iteración con un for en el siguiente dataframe. ¿Alguna idea?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = [15,20,14,18,14,13,12,15,17,16]

y = [3,2,3,1,4,3,2,3,1,2]

df = pd.DataFrame({'primera_fila': valores_1, 'segunda_fila': valores_2})

elemento_1 = df.iloc[:,0]

elemento_2 = df.iloc[:,1]
```

Comment: Te refieres a sumar por ejemplo 15+20 y a la vez 3+2? o como quieres sumarlos exactamente

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. A juzgar por la respuesta aceptada quieres sumar cada elemento de una columna con cada elemento de otra. Pero para eso no necesitas sacarlos antes a listas y hacer zip. Pandas puede hacerlo directamente, mediante lo que se denomina una operación **vectorizada** (actúa sobre todos los elementos de una columna "a la vez"): `columna_resultado = df.iloc[:,0] + df.iloc[:,1]` Tiene la ventaja de ser código más corto, al eliminar el bucle, y más rápido (al dejar la iteración en manos de pandas, que está escrito en C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes iterar por ambos elementos valiéndote de `zip()`, que crea tuplas de varios iterables, por ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd 

x = [15,20,14,18,14,13,12,15,17,16]
y = [3,2,3,1,4,3,2,3,1,2]

df = pd.DataFrame({'primera_fila': x, 'segunda_fila': y})

elemento_1 = df.iloc[:,0]
elemento_2 = df.iloc[:,1]

#print(elemento_1, elemento_2)

suma1 = 0
suma2 = 0
sumatodo = 0
for e1, e2 in zip(elemento_1, elemento_2):
    suma1 = suma1 + e1
    suma2 = suma2 + e2
    sumatodo = sumatodo + e1 + e2
    print(e1, e2)
    
print("suma 1", suma1)
print("suma 2", suma2)
print("suma todo", sumatodo)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta.